# Random Shuttdown(?) of Ubuntu Server

Tags: 18.04, crash

My server is shutting down (I guess) without any logs showing any indication of a shuttdown or crash. First I found an error report that was due to a Hard Disc failure. My hoster replaced the HDD and that works fine.

In the syslog I see nothing at all:

> [181164.633638] audit: type=1326 audit(1614084953.665:6796): auid=4294967295 uid=110 gid=65534 ses=4294967295 pid=31642 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" sig=31 arch=c000003$
> ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
> microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x21, date = 2019-02-13
> Linux version 4.15.0-135-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-005) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #139-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:38:24 UTC 2021 (Ubu$
> Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.15.0-135-generic root=UUID=8cb80d82-5a37-4ff9-a26f-ec11e9c8074b ro nomodeset consoleblank=0
> KERNEL supported cpus:
> systemd[1]: Started Availability of block devices.
> Intel GenuineIntel
> AMD AuthenticAMD
> Centaur CentaurHauls
> x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
> x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
> x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
> x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
> x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
> e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
> systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.

As far as I can tell it cuts of and then after my hoster restarts the Server manualy it starts normaly.

The command `sudo last -lx shutdown` or `sudo last -lx reboot` return the date of Feb 02 2021, where I last restarted the Server myself. The wierd thing is that the `@reboot` command in the crontab are not executed.

The folder `/var/crash` is empty. No report at all.

A hole Hardware check has been made by my Hoster but the Hardware is (as they say) not the Problem.

Comment: If you have s sudden hardware failure (CPU overheat, CPU fault, power flicker) it can't be logged (there's no working system). Problems of this nature must be diagnosed outside the software.

Comment: How do I determine if this is the cause? I do not have access to the Server hardware. Also my hoster (Hetzner if someone knows them) mostly uses standart responses so I guess they cant really help me tho. Any options?

Comment: Who is user "`uid=110 gid=65534`"? Why are they in group "`nobody`"? Why do they seem to be running `sshd`? What does Process Accounting (if it's on) say about pid 31642? Look at `sudo journalctl -b -1 _PID=31642` and `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`. Read `man journalctl`. I have `journalctl` hints in my AskUbuntu profile.

Comment: After `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, ask your provider what's in their logs at those times.  Remember, and remove, reboots unrelated to the sudden death problem.